# How do I override DeleteObject in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Hi i'm totally new to EF and i'm having difficulties getting my head around it but heres the scenario. I've created a project and added a edmx diagram which i've used to generate models from a pre-built SQL database. That dame diagram has generated code for each model an a context for me. the context looks something like :

```
public partial class BuzzEntities : ObjectContext
{
    public ObjectSet<Case> Cases
    {
        get
        {
            if ((_Cases == null))
            {
                _Cases = base.CreateObjectSet<Case>("Cases");
            }
            return _Cases;
        }
    }
```

ok so far this allows me to do things like

```
private Buzz.BuzzEntities db = new BuzzEntities();
db.Cases.DeleteObject(someCase);
```

which will delete the someCase from the database. However what i would like to do i override the delete method so that instead of deleting the object it marks a property of the object as deleted instead. i.e. someCase.Delete=true; The next part of the system is to prevent the system from loading cases with deleted=true. Basically i dont want the record ever deleted just hidden from the system.

Whats the best way to achieve this? I know i could manually change the field and just save the record instead of calling delete object but i dont want to worry about setting or hiding records in my UI i want the frame work to handle it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the options @Ladislav suggests, you could also create an [INSTEAD OF DELETE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191208.aspx) trigger for your table which remaps the delete at the DB server level, or [use SavingChanges to alter the state of the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942532/soft-deletes-ishistorical-column-with-entityframework/1946339#1946339).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override delete operation. You can create custom stored procedure and [map it to delete operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716711.aspx) of your entity. The second part of your problem can be achieved by using [conditional mapping](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94784/Using-Conditional-Mapping-in-Entity-Framework) where only entities with deleted != true will be used.